# FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar) return null

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use this example:
https://github.com/UdaraAlwis/Xamarin-Playground/tree/master/XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride.

But FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) return *null*.
In the new project this example working. On my project not working. What else can I check?

*MainAcitvity.cs*

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
            Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
            ToastNotification.Init(this);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

            DependencyService.Register<ToastNotification>();

            LoadApplication(new App());

            Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
```

*Toolbar.xml*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

*styles.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#172239</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

  <color name="ListViewHighlighted">@layout/gradient</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line

```
Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

When you didn't define the toolbar as `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` , it will been init as `Android..Widget.Toolbar`.So the method `FindViewById` will never find the toolbar in xml .

Instead it as the following line.

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar  = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

And you need to set the `MainPage` as a NavigationPage in app.xaml.cs .

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new xxxPage());
```